# How to scroll Flutter PageView in 2 different direction?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a PageView widget by which, I want to scroll next page by horizontal and if I scroll verticle, It navigates to another scaffold widget.

```
PageView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: controller,
      children: const <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('First Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Second Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Third Page'),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Please provide me any solution or resources. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any examples of this, or could you further elaborate exactly what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to perform verticle and horizontal, both the scroll direction in my app. one for loading new pageview and another for loading any other Stateful class or widget.

Comment: Just like inshorts news

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
PageView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: controller,
      children: const <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: 
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(
      children: const <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('Page1: 1st item'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Page1: 2nd item'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Page1: 3rd item'),
        )
      ],
),
),
        ),
        Center(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(
      children: const <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('Page2: 1st item'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Page2: 2nd item'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Page2: 3rd item'),
        )
      ],
),
),
        ),
        Center(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(
      children: const <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('Page3: 1st item'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Page3: 2nd item'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Page3: 3rd item'),
        )
      ],
),
),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: I want horizontal and verticle both the scroll view in same pageview